# DBT dependence error " The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'dbt_packages\\dbt_utils\\integration_tests'"

Tags: dbt

Getting error while running dbt deps:

my packages.yaml:

```
packages:
  - package: dbt-labs/dbt_utils
    version: "1.1.1"
  - package: calogica/dbt_expectations
    version: [">=0.9.0", "<0.10.0"]
```

below error I am getting :

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'dbt_packages\dbt_utils\integration_tests'

Can you please help me on this.